# Python доступ к файлу не зависимо от расположения

Tags: python, файлы, pygame

Пишу на Python игру '2048'. Есть такая иерархия папок:

```
*/pygame->src->resource(куча картинок),to_image.json, logic.py
```

В to_image.json находятся пути к каждой картинке относительно pygame (т.е `pygame/src/resource/image_1.png`).

Вопрос такой, как узнать путь до папки pygame? Просто если один пользователь закинет приложение в '`c:\games\2048\`'

Второй в '`d:\myDocyments\2048\`'

А третий в '`/home/usename/games/2048/`'

То как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное что приходит на ум - это узнать путь до Python скрипта:

```
import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: Блин,гениально), спасибо.